# rewrite and redirect

Tags: loops, redirect, url-rewriting, infinite

hi
i just applied a new url structure to my site
the links were like this before using rewrite mod
/detail.php?id=123
and after
/restaurant123.htm

but the problem is /detail.php?id=123 still work and i've spent a week to do something to redirect /detail.php?id=123 to /restaurant123.htm without an infinite loop
and i searched all over the internet but couldn't fix it
any idea?
thanks

Comment: What does your rewrite file look like?

Comment: RewriteRule ^(.*)restaurant([0-9]+)\.htm detail.php?id=$2 [L,QSA]

Answer (score 0):

I think you forget [the [L] flag](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/rewrite/rewrite_flags.html) in the RewriteRule of your .htaccess

Can we see your .htaccess ?

Comment: RewriteRule ^(.*)restaurant([0-9]+)\.htm detail.php?id=$2 [L,QSA]

Comment: and for the redirect i tried this code but it doesn't work RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]+\ /detail\.php\ HTTP/
RewriteRule ^detail\.php\?id=([0-9]+)$ http://www.118food.com/restaurant$1.htm [R=301,L]

Comment: You can try this to rewrite :  RewriteRule restaurant([0-9]+)\.htm detail.php?id=$1 [L,QSA]